# avahi-daemon stops randomly on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: linux, networking, mdns, avahi

I have a fresh installation of Raspberry OS on a Raspberry Pi 4. Avahi is running and can be queried by other hosts. The problem is that after "some time" (1 minute, sometimes 5) it stops to answer any query. Restarting avahi immediately solves the problem and the Raspberry can be queried again.

The raspberry is connected through Ethernet.

This is my `avahi-daemon.conf`

```
[server]
host-name=iot-ns-controller
domain-name=local
use-ipv4=yes
use-ipv6=yes
allow-interfaces=eth0
deny-interfaces=wlan0
ratelimit-interval-usec=1000000
ratelimit-burst=1000

[wide-area]
enable-wide-area=yes

[publish]
publish-hinfo=no
publish-workstation=no
```

Comment: Is some switch, AP, or other network middlebox, between your Pi and your query-sending device, doing IGMP snooping, by any chance? If a buggy IGMP snooper was forgetting that the Pi was subscribing to the ZeroConf (mDNS) multicast address (224.0.0.251), it could cause this. Restarting the Avahi daemon would cause a new IGMP request to go out, causing the buggy IGMP snooper to start letting those multicasts through again.

Comment: Oh wait are you saying that the avahi-daemon process is becoming stopped or terminated in some way? Like you've confirmed this with "ps"? Or is it still in full running state, just seemingly not responding to queries?

Comment: Actually `avahi` is up and running. The weird thing is that this seems to happen only when I am querying it from a Mac device.